# How to make <tr> in a table transparent in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a table which has a background color. But i was trying to keep a TR in that table transparent. I tried using `background-color:transparent` didnt worked. I used `!important`. Still didnt work. Can anyone please suggest where i am going wrong.

Below is my code.

```html
<table style="background: #EAE9E6 100%; width:30%;">
  <tr style="background: transparent !important;">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b>Yes</b>
      <b>No</b>
      <b>All</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Frog" value="0" />
      <input type="radio" name="Cat" value="0" />
      <input type="radio" name="Goat" value="0" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? I'm not sure I understand why you are applying a background color to the table if you don't want the rows of the table to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "override" a background applied to a parent element to 'cut through' it.

You'll need to apply a background to all rows that **aren't** the first one instead.

```css
table tr:not(:first-child) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:30%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Yes</b>
      <b>No</b>
      <b>All</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Frog" value="0" />
      <input type="radio" name="Cat" value="0" />
      <input type="radio" name="Goat" value="0" />

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="Frog" value="0" />
      <input type="radio" name="Cat" value="0" />
      <input type="radio" name="Goat" value="0" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, and it's not specific to tables. If any container has a background, you cannot undo the background in a child. Not even with clever use of z-indexes.